# Applications of matrix addition to image processing?

Tags: image-processing, matrix

What are the applications of matrix addition to image processing?And also is there any application in image processing which modifies current pixel value based on values of neighbour pixels?

Answer (score 1):

Strict addition is rare, but subtraction is more common, like when you subtract one image from its filtered one. For example you may subtract one image from its low pass filter and obtain its details.

Edit 1: Examples:  image addition (averaging) for noise suppression. Subtraction for change enhancement.

Lots of image processing algorithms modify the pixels based on its neighbors, like many *digital image filters*.
Take for example the *prewit* filter which emphasizes horizontal edges. Its *kernel* is:

```
[1 1 1
0 0 0
-1 -1 -1]
```

Here the current pixel value will be replaced by the sum of its the north-west, north and north-east pixel value, minus the sum of its south-west, south and south-east pixel value.
Similar kernels, for other applications, include *average*, *gaussian*, *laplacian*, *sobel*, etc.. Its is also possible to compute fast rough *distance maps*.

Comment: For matrix addition,I want specific application where you do addition several times..i have some background knowledge of DIP but i don't know exact area where it is crucial..

Comment: In edit I added noise suppression and change enhancement, which are two applications of addition for the whole image.